# Esri.ArcGISRuntime Exception : Object already owned in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to display a list and on click of it, another sub-list gets displayed with one map and list. The Map I am using is ArcGIS BaseMap.

1. I have done binding for 1st list and Map in GroupHeaderTemplate, and
2. Binding for 2nd list(expanded list) in ItemTemplate.
3. And as Map should also be displayed on click of the first list, initially I mark map's visibility as false and then handle it when the 1st list is clicked.

Required UI : [Expanded List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5LQv.jpg)

My 1st list is getting displayed and on click of it, the child list is also getting displayed but ArcGIS Map binding is giving error "Object already owned". Can anyone guide through this error?

Code :

```
//View :

    <ListView
                    x:Name="HotelsList"
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    HasUnevenRows="True"
                    IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                    RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadHotelsCommand}"
                    CachingStrategy="RetainElement">
                    <!--  GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource surveyListTemplateSelector}"-->

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  VerticalOptions="Center">
                                        <Label
                                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                            FontSize="Medium"
                                            Text="MapSheet 1"
                                            TextColor="Black"
                                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Grid >
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
                                        <Label
                                         FontAttributes="Bold"
                                         FontSize="Small"
                                         Text="{Binding HotelName}"
                                         TextColor="Gray"
                                         VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />

                                     <ContentView Content="{Binding MyMapView}"
                                                  HeightRequest="300"
                                                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                  IsVisible="{Binding IsMapVisible}"/>

                                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference currentPage}, Path=BindingContext.RefreshItemsCommand}"  NumberOfTapsRequired="1" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                </ListView>

//View Model for Map Binding:


    //MapView 
    private MapView _mapview;
    public MapView MyMapView
    {
        get => _mapview;
        set
        {
            _mapview = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyMapView"));
        }
    }
    //Map Visiblity
    private bool _mapvisible;
    public bool IsMapVisible
    {
        get { return _mapvisible; }
        set
        {
            _mapvisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsMapVisible"));
        }
    }

    // Property that handles expansion and collapse event of parent listview
    private bool _expanded;
    public bool Expanded
    {
        get { return _expanded; }
        set
        {
            if (_expanded != value)
            {
                _expanded = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Expanded"));
                if (_expanded)
                {
                    IsMapVisible = true;
                    MyMapView = new MapView()
                    {
                        Map = new Map(Basemap.CreateNavigationVector());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    IsMapVisible = false;
                    MyMapView = null;
                    this.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: A layer can only belong to one map, and a map as well as graphics overlays can only belong to one mapview at a time.So if you are reusing your overlays, make sure they get disconnected from the old mapview before assigning them to a new mapview. You can see this link:https://community.esri.com/thread/211980-esriarcgisruntimearcgisruntimeexception-object-already-owned-already-owned

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the following code in OnAppearing

```
if (map.OperationalLayers != null)
    map.OperationalLayers.Clear();

if (MyMapView.GraphicsOverlays.Any())
    MyMapView.GraphicsOverlays.Clear();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as I am showing Map based on visibility property, I added your code into the getter with visibility== false check. But, I am still getting the error